# Rename tag burn-fat?

Tags: discussion, tags

I propose to rename the tag [burn-fat](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/burn-fat) to [fatburning](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fatburning) it just sounds odd to me.

I am not sure if there are any naming rules for verbs on StackExchange sites, but it would come in line with tags like [weightlifting](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weightlifting), actually most taggified verbs I have seen on SE site are in the `~ing` form to make them (sound like) a noun. I have never seen the neutral `to ~` form before.

Comment: @NathanWheeler Well, the correct term actually would be `gerund`. :P I don't think that weight-loss is a good substitute as there are some questions ([example](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/8248/3941)) that don't aim to lose weight but just reduce the body fat percentage.

Comment: I converted my comments to an answer, so the community can decide. I'm still open to rebuttal in comments though. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think we should probably consolidate [burn-fat](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/burn-fat) and [weight-loss](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weight-loss). The [weight-loss](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weight-loss) tag is defined as "How to lower one's body/fat ratio. Questions are about diets and training programs that improve body composition."

The *definition* of [weight-loss](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weight-loss) fits nicely with [burn-fat](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/burn-fat) or [fatburning](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fatburning), but the name isn't necessarily congruent, and might be changed to [fat-loss](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fat-loss) rather than [weight-loss](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weight-loss), because typically when people talk about losing weight, they're targeting fat, not anything else (bone, muscle, etc.)

Comment: Agree, some people might want to burn fat but build muscle, thus gaining weight...

Comment: I just wanted to retag those [tag:burn-fat] questions to [tag:fat-loss], but then I saw that it already redirects to [tag:weight-loss]. Is there a way to un-synonimize it?

Answer (score 0):

[body-recomposition](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/body-recomposition) is the term we're looking for here.

Weight-loss is not accurate, since many people want to maintain their current weight while losing fat mass. I think I wrote the weight-loss tag wiki, but regardless, defining weight loss as body recomposition is not accurate. Some people want to get smaller. Other people want to stay the same size but have less fat. They are not the same.

Comment: That's why I proposed changing the whole thing to fat-loss. That way it covers either scenario: fat loss without muscle gain, and fat loss with muscle replacement.

Comment: Although body recomposition might be correct, for me it is far too complicated. Remember that there are a lot of nonnative english speakers on the SE sites, too.